# Jquery function is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a log in page, there is a form and what i wanna do is when the user enters their username and password, it checks it in an object (ik i should do it in backend but stay with me here) but the jquery function is not working. here is the code.

```
    <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="ID" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Enter Workspace</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <script>
        $('#but').click(function() { 
            alert("lol");   
        });
    </script>
```

what do i neeed to fix in order for the jquery function to work?

Comment: In what way does the function not work?

Comment: I do not see `click-handler` not [___working___](https://jsfiddle.net/anjgwofs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding jquery in the script. Also you may write the jquery functions in `$(document).ready()` or `$(function(){})` but it as optional as long as your write your script after the element it is trying to access.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="ID" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <button id="but" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Enter Workspace</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#but').click(function() { 
            alert("lol");   
        });
      })
        
    </script>
```

Comment: @J.doe what for. Did my solution answer your question

Comment: Seriously a downVote, care to explain the reason for it. Thats what the OP asked and not that he cannot find a way to get values. He wasn't able to run the jquery function

Comment: If `<script>` is `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`)), why will this fail ?

Comment: @Rayon I did not tell that it will fail, I told in order for jquery function to run, include jquery in your script and write the jquery functions in document.ready()

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri – I have been coding for quit a long time and I have never used `document.ready()` in my code and it never troubled me.. So what is the point ? By the way, I am not the one who pressed the `down` button..

Comment: I suspect the downvote was because the first version of this answer was just a block of code, and `$(function(){})` is about as clear as mud.  If you're going to prefer that version over the _much more clear_ `$(document).ready()`, you should at least explain what you're doing.

Comment: @aroth Well I accidently clicked submit. and then immediately edited my answer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri – Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`)) and you will never scratch your head again.. It is about understanding what it does and why it is needed.. I will compare it with `DOMContentLoaded` though they are not same but if you are accessing element after it is in the `DOM`, you do not need to test/check anything again..

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I agree that using a document ready handler is not necessary as long as the script element appears after whatever elements it tries to access (which is indeed the case in the code shown in the question), so if this answer mentions document ready at all it should be made clear that that part is optional.

Comment: i was checking for document ready function and stuff like dat but i forgot to include the CDN lol

Comment: guys chill out. i derped out and forgot to include the jQuery CDN. and ik about the document.ready function rules. thanks @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'it checks it in an object'? Do you want to grab the username & password when a user clicks the button? If so then you'd do something like this:

```
$('#but').click(function() { 
   var username=$('input[name=u]').val();
   var password = $('input[name=p]').val();
   // Do checks with the values here e.g send to server for validation
 });
```

Comment: Surely you want to have some `.val()` calls in there?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @aroth - just forgot to put them in

Comment: No worries @J.doe  - Try put a bit more time into your questions next time - Just a tip =)